# How Do I run ulimit -c unlimited automatically

Tags: c, linux, coredump, ulimit, rootfs

I am trying to provide support for coredump file generation from my rootfs ,I have modified /etc/limits file with "ulimit -c unlimited" command and "* hard core -1" ,Now when I give kill -6 $$ ,expecting core file generation but to get this core file have to run ulimit -c unlimited explicitly .

But I want it to happen automatically , no need to run ulimit -c unlimited it again in shell.

Can anybody tell me what changes I have to make for the same to happen

Comment: Put it in your `.profile` file?

Comment: Add the line to your shell startup file, maybe to `~/.profile`.

Comment: Might wanna read up on [this](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html). Looks like you could do with some info on how to set up your own profile file.

Comment: Well for given reasons can't put it into profile file,If I change into profile file ,This will only take affect for program launched from a login shell, not for processes/services started by systemd. /etc/limits would the the proper location for settings these defaults.This reason have been told

Comment: @Nobilis would you like to comment on the above

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar My understanding is that since you still have to run `ulimit -c unlimited` explicitly (presumably from the command line) you could still benefit from putting it into your profile.

Comment: @Nobils but the would it be true "This will only take affect for program launched from a login shell, not for processes/services started by system"

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar Looking at alk's answer this looks like a way to have the application take care of the core dump. However, I still think putting the call in `.profile` will be of help, since you have to run it yourself separately anyway (by the sound of things). You can certainly try and see if it works :)

Answer (score 6):

From a program you can use `setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, ...)` to set the core file's maximum size. To specify an infinite size pass `RLIM_INFINITY`.

For details on this please read here: http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=getrlimit&sektion=2

---

Using the `sysctl` command you can do

```
sysctl kernel.core_pattern=/var/core/core.%p
```

to have the kernel create cores named `core.<pid>` in `/var/core`.

Adding `kernel.core_pattern=/var/core/core.%p` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` makes it permanent. (run `sysctl -p` to process your changes to `/etc/sysctl.conf`)

Besides `%p` (for the process id) there are other placeholders as follows ([taken from here](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=core&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en)):

```
%%  a single % character
%p  PID of dumped process
%u  (numeric) real UID of dumped process
%g  (numeric) real GID of dumped process
%s  number of signal causing dump
%t  time  of dump, expressed as seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)
%h  hostname (same as nodename returned by uname(2))
%e  executable filename (without path prefix)
%E  pathname of executable, with slashes ('/') replaced by exclamation marks ('!').
%c  core  file  size soft resource limit of crashing process (since Linux 2.6.24)
```

Comment: Thanks @alk ,something like this I am looking for ,So I need to specify sysctl kernel.core_pattern=/var/cor/core.%p in my /etc/sysctl.conf ?? and Do I really need to run ulimit -c unlimited explicitly then??

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: `kernel.core_pattern` specifies **where** to place the core file and **how** to name it.

Comment: Fine @alk but the it won't solve my problem,Cav we set core file's maximum size in /etc/limits file?

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: You might like to use `setrlimit()` from aout of your program to she the maximum size of the core file, as proposed by my answer.

Comment: yes @alk that is what I am looking into .Do you know where in Linux code its been set.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: `setrlimit()` is a C function which could be called from your code directly. For details on this please see here: http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=getrlimit&sektion=2